# How to get WorkRequest Id inside CoroutineWorker

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack, android-workmanager, workmanagers

I have a situation where I need to send `WorkRequest.id` to CoroutineWorker.

I'm dealing with Room DB from `CoroutineWorker`, now in one of the Column in DB, I need to store WorkRequest.id (UUID) so that when a user cancels a task from list of task in recyclerview, I can come to know which WorkRequest UUID to cancel.

Now my problem is that WorkRequest's id is created after the data is assigned to `setInputData()`, so before the id created, how can I send the WorkRequest.id to my worker.

Is there a way I can send extra data to CoroutineWorker after the WorkRequest is created ?

Comment: I think You can call `#getId()` in `CoroutineWorker` to get the id  `WorkRequest`  that created it . It comes from `ListenableWorker` so you should be able to call it . If thats what you are asking . make me clear if i understood wrong.

Comment: @ADM Yeah! #getId() is what I needed. I just tried it and its working. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call [#getId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/ListenableWorker#getId()) in `CoroutineWorker` to get the id `WorkRequest` that created it . It comes from `ListenableWorker` so you should be able to call it .